# What's the difference between node.js Buffer and WebAssembly Memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly

I wonder if it's possible to substitute Node.js 
[Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) memory allocation with WebAssembly [Memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory)?

If yes, is there any advantages?

Comment: This question is like asking what the difference is between the glove box of a Volvo vs the engine hood of a BMW. Sure, both contain stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In node.js both `Buffer` and WebAssembly `Memory` objects have a `buffer` property which is of type [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) which itself is defined as part of [Typed Arrays in ECMAScript/JavaScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects).

```
node --version
v8.1.2
node
> mem = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 10});
Memory {}
> buf = new Buffer("abc")
<Buffer 61 62 63>
> mem.buffer
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 655360 }
> buf.buffer
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 8192 }
```

A plain ArrayBuffer object is just a container for a stream of bytes. In order to access and use it you have to wrap/convert it to a Typed Array (e.g. Uint8Array, DataView, etc), a node.js Buffer, or a WebAssembly Memory.

Comment: tks for the answer @kanaka. i didn't know both have an ArrayBuffer underneath. with that, does is make sense to use WebAssembly Memory or directly use ArrayBuffer over node.js Buffer?

Comment: It really depend on what you are trying to accomplish. You can copy pretty efficiently between typed arrays (especially if you use the `set` method) so it's probably not a big performance issue to have different types for different purposes and convert/copy as needed unless what you are doing is _really_ performance sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

One significant difference is that `WebAssembly.Memory` is resizable via [`Memory.prototype.grow`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblymemoryprototypegrow) while `Buffer` is not.

Another is that `WebAssembly.Memory` is designed so that hardware memory protection can be used to remove dynamic bounds checks and thus its length is clamped to a multiple of 64kb.  `Buffer` can have an arbitrary byte length.